# Custom basemap with Map on load

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I am using ArcGIS JavaScript 4.x. I am trying to add a basemap to my map while the map is loading the first time. The projection of Mapview and the basemap layer are different. It works fine when the basemap is in basemap gallery, but the same does not work while first time map load. Has any one faced similar issue before?

```
baseLayer = new TileLayer({
    url: baseMapService.MapServiceURL
});
// map.add(layer);
var myBasemap = new Basemap({
    baseLayers: [baseLayer],
    thumbnailUrl: baseMapService.MapServiceURL + '/info/thumbnail',
    title: 'My custom basemap',
    id: 'my_custom_basemap'
});
map.basemap = myBasemap;
```

Comment: You want to add the `TileLayer` as a layer or as the basemap?

Comment: Yes. The layer is cached.

Comment: How are you creating the map instance, can you add the code please?. Can you specify the heigh, width and scales of the levels of the custom basemap?.

Comment: I just managed to fix it by changing the view spatial reference to basemap reference.  baseLayer = new TileLayer({
    url: baseMapService.MapServiceURL
});
// map.add(layer);
var myBasemap = new Basemap({
    baseLayers: [baseLayer],
    thumbnailUrl: baseMapService.MapServiceURL + '/info/thumbnail',
    title: 'My custom basemap',
    id: 'my_custom_basemap'
});
map.basemap = myBasemap;  mapView.spatialrefrence = baseMapService.spatialrefrence;